# Wrong icon after application startup

Tags: 15.04, icons, ubuntu-gnome

I have two Eclipse installations and for each of them a desktop file, see below.

For the icons, I'm using `eclipse` in both cases with an activated Numix Icon Theme.

If I search and start the applications via Activities, the icons are correct.

[image]

But not in the taskbar on the left hand side after the start

[image]

How can I change this behaviour, I want the Numix icons on the left hand side also.

---

*Some more details*

`find /usr/share/icons/Numix-Circle -iname "*eclipse*"`

```
/usr/share/icons/Numix-Circle/48x48/apps/redeclipse.svg
/usr/share/icons/Numix-Circle/48x48/apps/eclipse.svg
```

`cat ~/.local/share/applications/opt_eclipse_cpp.desktop`

```
[Desktop Entry]
Encoding=UTF-8
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Name=Eclipse C++
Comment=Eclipse Integrated Development Environment
Icon=eclipse
Exec=/opt/eclipse-cpp/eclipse/eclipse
StartupNotify=true
StartupWMClass=Eclipse-CPP
```

`cat ~/.local/share/applications/opt_eclipse.desktop`

```
[Desktop Entry]
Encoding=UTF-8
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Name=Eclipse JEE
Comment=Eclipse Integrated Development Environment
Icon=eclipse
Exec=/opt/eclipse-jee/eclipse/eclipse
StartupNotify=true
StartupWMClass=Eclipse-Java
```

Comment: Is this a sudden change in behaviour, or has it always been like this?

Comment: @ParanoidPanda Not suddenly. The problem occurred immediately in my old GNOME 3.14 and in GNOME 3.16.

Comment: It could be a bug, if you haven't made any changes lately that could have caused this issue, it is likely to be a bug, and even if you can get a fix or workaround from here, filing a bug report would probably be a good thing to do.

Comment: I have a very similar problem. Installed Gnome on 16.04. Installed and created .desktop for Netscape Navigator. Now when I start Firefox in Gnome it shows as Netscape Navigator with its icon. Not a problem in Unity or Xfce, only in Gnome.

Comment: Are you sure those `StartupWMClass` entries have correct values?

Comment: @pomsky three years later? No :D

Comment: @A.B. Well, the issue seems to be [still relevant](https://askubuntu.com/q/991592/480481) :D usually a correct `StartupWMClass` entry fixes it.